# Redirect a href link to an external application

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

In a link in my web application it is possible to redirect to an external site and load as activated a specific bootstrap tab. This external site I do not have access to the source code.

In the site that I have access to the source code I can use something like this:

```
// trigger additional clicks
$ ('. tab-link') on ('click', function (event) {
     // Prevent url change
     event.preventDefault ();
    
     // `this` is the clicked <a> tag
     $ ('[data-toggle = "tab"] [trigger =' '+ this.hash +' "'').
})
```

Is it possible to do this without being able to put code on the site, just with the browser's address bar?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the location attribute on the window object to the url you want

```
// Sets the new location of the current window.
window.location = "https://www.example.com";
```

Comment: I think I expressed myself poorly, it's to open with the specified tab enabled.
I want to open an external site with tab2 selected. As if it were an anchor, something like this: http://www.YourSite.org/#tab2